# wxPython : Ubuntu : change screen resolution

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, wxpython

I am developing a GUI wxPython application for 800x480 screen resolution and below is the screen resolution that my desktop can support:

```
# xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768        0.0* 
   800x600         0.0  
   640x480         0.0
```

How can I set programmatically screen resolution to 800x480?

Comment: You shouldn't, unless you want to make something like a game that takes over the screen. Otherwise, you should just open a window of the dimensions you want.

Comment: Your desktop computer doesn't support 800x480 so you can't. I don't know but maybe if you run second linux on virtual machine (like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) **in window** then you could set any resolution by changing **window** size manually.

Comment: Please confirm how a screen resolution of 800x400 can be achieved by re-sizing the window if the current resolution is 1024 x 768?